# CSS Rotate Image XY

Tags: html, css, image

I have done with some examples a rotate image:

```css
.image {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #0080FF;
    margin: 100px auto;
    -webkit-animation: rotateplane 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
    animation: rotateplane 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotateplane {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(120px)
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateY(180deg)
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateY(180deg) rotateX(180deg)
    }
}
@keyframes rotateplane {
    0% {
        transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
        -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg)
    }
    50% {
        transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180.1deg) rotateY(0deg);
        -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180.1deg) rotateY(0deg)
    }
    100% {
        transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180deg) rotateY(-179.9deg);
        -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180deg) rotateY(-179.9deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<img class="image" src="http://makeameme.org/media/templates/120/grumpy_cat.jpg" alt="" width="120" height="120">
```

But i would like to see the image allways face up instead of face down and with the stren ... if you see the example you will understand (dificult to explain it in english for me).

Comment: sorry first time i do it... and i was not able to add the code (4 spaces) now get it... hope some help ... thanks

Comment: That is ok mate. No worries as janfoeh has already done it for you. With the code in question is worthy of a vote because you have clearly depicted what is going wrong and what you need help fixing. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for scaleX(-1) and scaleY(-1) to flip your image.

Snippet :

```css
.image {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #0080FF;
    margin: 100px auto;
    -webkit-animation: rotateplane 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
    animation: rotateplane 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotateplane {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) scaleX(1) scaleY(1)
    }
    25% {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateY(90deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1)
    }
    25.1% {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateY(90deg) scaleX(-1) scaleY(1)
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateY(180deg) scaleX(-1) scaleY(1)
    }
    75% {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateY(180deg) rotateX(90deg) scaleX(-1) scaleY(1)
    }
    75.1% {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateY(180deg) rotateX(90deg) scaleX(-1) scaleY(-1)
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateY(180deg) rotateX(180deg) scaleX(-1) scaleY(-1)
    }
}
@keyframes rotateplane {
    0% {
        transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1);
        -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1)
    }
    25% {
        transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1);
        -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1)
    }
    25.1% {
        transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(-1);
        -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(-1)
    }
    50% {
        transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180.1deg) rotateY(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(-1);
        -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180.1deg) rotateY(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(-1)
    }
    75% {
        transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180.1deg) rotateY(-90deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(-1);
        -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180.1deg) rotateY(-90deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(-1)
    }
    75.1% {
        transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180.1deg) rotateY(-90deg) scaleX(-1) scaleY(-1);
        -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180.1deg) rotateY(-90deg) scaleX(-1) scaleY(-1)
    }
    100% {
        transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180deg) rotateY(-179.9deg) scaleX(-1) scaleY(-1);
        -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180deg) rotateY(-179.9deg) scaleX(-1) scaleY(-1);
    }
}
```

```html
<img class="image" src="http://makeameme.org/media/templates/120/grumpy_cat.jpg" alt="" width="120" height="120">
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of rotating Y in the last transformation `@keyframe 100%` I applied a vertical flip,  here's the snippet:

```css
.image {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #0080FF;
    margin: 100px auto;
    -webkit-animation: rotateplane 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
    animation: rotateplane 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotateplane {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(120px)
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateY(180deg)
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) scaleY(-1) rotateX(180deg)
    }
}
@keyframes rotateplane {
    0% {
        transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
        -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg)
    }
    50% {
        transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180.1deg) rotateY(0deg);
        -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180.1deg) rotateY(0deg)
    }
    100% {
        transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180deg)  scaleY(-1) ;
        -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180deg) scaleY(-1);
    }
}
```

```html
<img class="image" src="http://makeameme.org/media/templates/120/grumpy_cat.jpg" alt="" width="120" height="120">
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you would like to avoid that in the end, the image "flips" immediately from being on its head to being right side up.

You could 'alternate' the animation: with that keyword, in the end it stops and animates backwards:

```css
.image {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #0080FF;
    margin: 100px auto;
    -webkit-animation: rotateplane 1.2s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate ;
    animation: rotateplane 1.2s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotateplane {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(120px)
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateY(180deg)
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateY(180deg) rotateX(180deg)
    }
}
@keyframes rotateplane {
    0% {
        transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
        -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg)
    }
    50% {
        transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180.1deg) rotateY(0deg);
        -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180.1deg) rotateY(0deg)
    }
    100% {
        transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180deg) rotateY(-179.9deg);
        -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180deg) rotateY(-179.9deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<img class="image" src="http://makeameme.org/media/templates/120/grumpy_cat.jpg" alt="" width="120" height="120">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like

```css
0% {
    transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(0deg)   rotateY(0deg);
}
25% {
    transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(0deg);
}
25.0001% {
    transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(90deg)  rotateY(0deg);
}
50% {
    transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(0deg)   rotateY(0deg);
}
75% {
    transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(0)      rotateY(-90deg);
}
75.001% {
    transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(0)      rotateY(90deg);
}
100% {
    transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(0deg)   rotateY(0deg);
}
```

```css
.image {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #0080FF;
    margin: 100px auto;
    -webkit-animation: rotateplane 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
    animation: rotateplane 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotateplane {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    }
    25% {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(0deg);
    }
    25.0001% {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(90deg) rotateY(0deg);
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    }
    75% {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(0) rotateY(-90deg);
    }
    75.001% {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(0) rotateY(90deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    }
}
@keyframes rotateplane {
    0% {
        transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    }
    25% {
        transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(0deg);
    }
    25.0001% {
        transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(90deg) rotateY(0deg);
    }
    50% {
        transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    }
    75% {
        transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(0) rotateY(-90deg);
    }
    75.001% {
        transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(0) rotateY(90deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<img class="image" src="http://makeameme.org/media/templates/120/grumpy_cat.jpg" alt="" width="120" height="120">
```